# $\alpha$-trimmed mean vs. sample mean (comprehension questions)

Tags: statistics, means

Suppose that we have $n$ observations : $ x_1, ...,x_n$. ( sort them ).
We get $ x_{(1)}, ...,x_{(n)}$

For $\alpha \in [0,\frac{1}{2}) $ we define the $\alpha$-trimmed mean :

$$ T_{\alpha}=\frac{1}{n-2\lceil{\alpha n}\rceil}  \sum_{i=\lceil{\alpha n}\rceil +1}^{n-\lceil{\alpha n}\rceil} x_{(i)}$$

and the sample mean is : $$ S= \frac{1}{n}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{(i)} $$

> $1)$ What happens when a fraction of the observations, say $k$ observations, with $k < \alpha\cdot n$, is huge? Illustrate the effect for $k$ observations tending to infinity on the sample mean and on the $\alpha$-trimmed mean. Explain why the $\alpha$-trimmed mean may be problematic in real life applications
>   compared to the sample mean.
>
> $2)$ Suppose in the setting of part $1)$, that $k \geq 2n \cdot\alpha $. How does this affect the $\alpha$-trimmed mean?
>
> $3)$ Explain why the trimmed mean may be advantageous compared to the sample
>   mean in a real life application, with respect to its robustness.

*My idea:*

For $1)$ I've considered an example. If we have $n=9$ , $\alpha = 0.3$ ( $k$ has to be $2$ then) with:

$x_{(1)}=4,x_{(2)}=7,x_{(3)}=8,x{(4)}_=10,x_{(5)}=12,x_{(6)}=23,x_{(7)}=231,x_{(8)}=323333,x_{(9)}=4567564$

Then: $S ≈ 543466$, while $T_{0.3}= 15$. If we now replace $x_{(8)}$ and $x_{(9)}$ by something higher [for example: $400.000$ and $987654321$] (because we want that the $k$ observations tends to infinity ) then we get $S ≈ 109783846$, while $T_{0.3}=15$. So my answer for $1)$ would be that $S$ tending to infinity, while the $k$ observations has no effect on $T_{0.3}$,right? Like you see I have used an example here. Can you help me with the illustration? for the second question of $1)$ I will consider the example above with $\alpha = 0,4$. Then only $x_{(5)}$ would be left. So $T_{0.4} =12 $.  So only one observation decides what the trimmed mean is. This is obviously not good, if you want to make a statement of a certain situation. Is this the answer, which is expected?

$2)$ I would say that $T_{\alpha}$ tends to infinity? Because at least one of the observations, which tending to infinity is in $T_{\alpha}$. But my answer is really short? Did I really figure out what the exercise wants to show me?

$3)$ So the trimmed mean is obviously less sensitive to outliers than the sample mean and still illustrates the central tendency. ( see that in $(1)$ ) But to be honest: I don't figured out which advantage "hides" in $(2)$. Can you help me here?

Thank you for your help and correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two comments on trimmed means (illustrated in R) that may be helpful.

**Fifty percent trimmed mean is median:** If the fraction trimmed from each tail is nearly 1/2, the trimmed mean
is (nearly) the median. It is not true that only one (or two) observations *determine*
the trimmed mean because the relative positions of the other observations
influence which one(s) are not trimmed. Here is an illustration in R.

```
mean(x); mean(x, trim=.499);  median(x)
[1] 105.6938
[1] 70.74927
[1] 70.74927
sort(x)[498:502]
[1] 69.90573 70.61226 70.69725 70.80129 70.86220
```

**Robust estimate of mean for contaminated data.** In practice, the trimmed mean is especially useful if observed data are mainly from
a target distribution, but are subject to 'contamination' by a much
different distribution a small percentage of the time. For target
distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(100, 15),$ contamination $\mathsf{Norm}(200, 50),$
and contamination is 3%, here is an example:

```
m = 1000;  av = adj.av = numeric(m)
mu = 100;  sg = 15;  c.mu = 200;  c.sg = 50;  c.rat = .03
b = rbinom(1000, 1, c.rat)
x = (1-b)*rnorm(m, mu, sg) + b*rnorm(m, c.mu, c.sg)
mean(x);  mean(x, trim=.05);  median(x)
[1] 103.9161
[1] 100.9978
[1] 100.4297
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! I totally forget the "relative positions"-point. Thank you for your detailed answer.